# How tos one user can access folder of other users under /home/south

Tags: linux, home

I have 4users, under **/home/south** , user1....user4, if user1 want to see the folder of /home/south/user2 + /home/south/user3 + /home/south/user4. How to set permission to access, and groupname is South.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a group (if you havnt already) that will be the group for the folders /home/south/user2, /home/south/user3 and /home/south/user4
you can use the command:
 groupadd south

Next you need to add user1 to your new group:
usermod -a -G south user1

Once this is done you need to set your new group to the group for the folders user2, user3 and user4 to do this you can use the command:
chown -R user2:south /home/south/user2

This will set the folder /home/south/user2 to have a owner of user2 and the group will be your new group. repeat this for the other two folders.
Finally you may need to set the permissions to allow the group access to the folder you can do this with the command:
chmod 770 /home/south/user2